# Wistia.com video is not getting closed after clicking on close button in chrome browser

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, wistia

Video popup close button is not working in chrome browser.

Given: When clicking “watch” on a page for a Wistia embedded video

When: You click the “X” to close the video modal window

Then: The video continues to play in the background even though it is no longer visible. Issue is comming chrome browser only.

This is likely true for all Wistia embedded videos that open in a modal window.

I want it should close the video completely after clicking on close button

Comment: To ask a good question you should show us what you tried. What code is used to create the popup? How is it closed? This is too broad and we can't really help you.

Comment: hi i am using wistia.com api

Comment: that is in no way helping. We can't guess what your code looks like.

Comment: using below code for wistia video
<div id="wistia_qnfh383nxr" class="wistia_embed" style="width:640px;height:400px;" data-video-width="640" data-video-height="400">&nbsp;</div>
<script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/playlist-v1.js"></script>
<script>
wistiaPlaylist = Wistia.playlist("qnfh383nxr", {
  version: "v1",
  videoOptions: {
    volumeControl: true,
    playerColor: "39404F",
    autoPlay: true,
    videoWidth: "640",
    videoHeight: "400"
  },
  media_0_0: {
    autoPlay: false,
    controlsVisibleOnLoad: false
  }
});
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the element containing the video is not properly removed.

Make sure to *remove the embedded video directly* and/or use a *javascript trigger to pause* it.